# Marklogic API LATEST/Search? documents Mulitpart/mixed

Tags: api, url, marklogic, multipart

I want to use a GET URL to search and return a group of documents from MarkLogic API.
If I use a POST method I can set the Accpets:multipart/mixed header and return what I want. The environment I am using can only send  GET URL.

How do I either add multipart/mixed to  GET URL or how do I pass to MarkLogic API return documents.
The argument view=none returns an error

```
REST-UNSUPPORTEDPARAM: (err:FOER0000) Endpoint does not support query parameter: Can use the 'none' value for the 'view' parameter only with multipart/mixed accept
```

Comment: What is the constraint in your environment restricting you to GET requests? Is it a limitation of the tooling/apps(which ones) or some other restriction (gateway/proxy/firewall only allowing GET)? If you can provide some additional information about your tooling and constraints, we can help suggest ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You indicate that you accept multipart/mixed by setting the `Accept` request header.

For example, with cURL:

```
curl --anyauth --user user:password -X GET -i \
  -H "Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY" \
  'http://localhost:8000/LATEST/search?view=none'
```

If you are trying to issue a GET search request from your browser with `view=none`, simply typing in the URL and hitting return may not work.

However, you can still make it work. For example, in FireFox you can:

- Pop open the developer toolbar
- Select the request
- Under the "**headers**" tab, to the right of the status code, click the "**edit and resend**" button
- In the **Request Headers** textarea, add "`Accept: multipart/mixed; boundary=BOUNDARY`"
- Click the "**Send**" button
- Select the newly issued request, click the "**Response**" tab to view your multipart response